# VBA SendKeys to another window not working

Tags: vba, pdf, sendkeys

I have the following macro which is intended to quickly switch two PDFs. After 8 quick switches macro should go to the next pages of both PDFs and repeat the procedure. Unfortunately, macro scrolls first declared PDF only. Any ideas how to amend it?

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function BringWindowToTop Lib "user32" (ByVal lngHWnd As LongPtr) As LongPtr

Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr

Private Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMiliseconds As Long)


Sub switching_pdfs()

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

ptr1 = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Some PDF 1.pdf - Acrobat Reader")
ptr2 = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Some PDF 2.pdf - Acrobat Reader")

For i = 1 To 30
    For j = 1 To 4
       BringWindowToTop (ptr1)
       Sleep 100
       BringWindowToTop (ptr2)
       Sleep 100
    Next j
BringWindowToTop (ptr1)
Application.SendKeys "{RIGHT}": Sleep 500: DoEvents 'should move to the next page in the first PDF
BringWindowToTop (ptr2)
Application.SendKeys "{RIGHT}": Sleep 500: DoEvents 'should move to the next page in the second PDF
Next i
End Sub
```

I also tried to use SendMessage, but it does not want to move any PDF to the next page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This approach. Tested and Working. You may change the Wait numbers to make the delay longer. Make sure the PDF files are named properly and there are no extra Spaces on the file name.

```
Sub switching_pdfs()
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim ptr1 As String, ptr2 As String
    ptr1 = "Some PDF 1.pdf - Acrobat Reader"
    ptr2 = "Some PDF 2.pdf - Acrobat Reader"

    For i = 1 To 30
        For j = 1 To 4
           AppActivate ptr1
           Wait 0.5
           AppActivate ptr2
           Wait 0.5
        Next j
        AppActivate ptr1
        Send "{RIGHT}"
        Wait 1
        AppActivate ptr2
        Send "{RIGHT}"
        Wait 1
    Next i
End Sub
Function Send(pData As String)
    SendKeys pData, True
    Wait 0.5
End Function
Function Wait(Optional pWaitTime As Single = 0.1)
    Dim StartTime
    StartTime = Timer
    Do While (Timer < StartTime + pWaitTime)
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Ricardo, thank you for the code, I checked that changing only BringWindowToTop to AppActivate (as you suggested) makes the code working as well.

Comment: Glad I helped in some way.